# how to remove duplicate div sections?

Tags: jquery

I am appending data output into this div section.

Within this `<div>` section, there are `<div>` sections that are duplicates. How can I remove the latter duplicates?

Example coding to remove:

```
<div id=EXTRACTION_a>something ...</div>
<div id=EXTRACTION_b>something ...</div>
<div id=EXTRACTION_c>something ...</div>
<div id=EXTRACTION_a>something ...</div>
<div id=EXTRACTION_b>something ...</div>
<div id=EXTRACTION_a>something ...</div>
<div id=EXTRACTION_c>something ...</div>
<div id=EXTRACTION_d>something ...</div>
<div id=EXTRACTION_a>something ...</div>
```

I want to keep the first occurances of a,b,c,d and remove the rest.

I tried this coding but not working:

```
            var count = -1;
            \$("div[id^='EXTRACTION_']").each(function(){
               count ++;
               var ids = \$('[id='+this.id+']');
               var originaldivsectin = \$(this);

               var count2 = 0;
               \$("div[id^='EXTRACTION_']").each(function(){
                    count2 ++;
                    var copyids = \$('[id='+this.id+']');
                    var dupdivsection = \$(this);
                    if (count != count2 && copyids.length>1 && ids[count]==copyids[count2])
                    {
                        dupdivsection.remove();   
                    }
               });

               // if(ids.length>1 && ids[0]==this)
               // {  
               //       \$(this).remove();
               //       alert('Multiple IDs #'+this.id);
               // }
            });
```

Note: jquery is still a new language for me

Comment: What is _this_ section? Can you post the html?

Comment: An example of code would be nice.

Comment: By duplicates you mean DIVs that have the exact same content?

Comment: coding would be complex as it is integrated with some perl. I have this perl script which keeps generating html data which appends to a div section say id=file. The generating data might contain div tags with id=something. Once in a while, there might be a div=something which is identical in everyway to div=something.

Comment: @Gordon: So you're simply saying that a duplicate is defined as two elements potentially having a matching ID attribute?

Comment: yes, i will update my coding with a more specific example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT:** Based on your update, I see that you only want to remove certain elements based on a potentially matching ID, and that there could be several matches of each type.

You can do this instead:

[***Click here to test a working example.** <sup>(jsFiddle)</sup>*](http://www.jsfiddle.net/JfPQ7/)

```
var found = {}; // Container to hold each unique ID that we find.

$('div[id^=EXTRACTION_]').filter(function() {
    var ending = this.id.replace("EXTRACTION_","");
    if( found.hasOwnProperty( ending ) ) {
        return this;
    } else {
        found[ ending ] = ending;
    }
}).remove();
```

Basically using the [`attribute-starts-with-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) we select all elements that start with `EXTRACTION_`. *(I also added the `div` to the selector. If they're not all `divs`, remove that.)*

Then we [`filter()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) them. In the filter, first we extract the unique part of the ID. Then we check to see if that ID is a property of an object we created called `found`. If it isn't, add it as a property. If it is already a property, that means we already came across it, so we do `return this`, which will cause the `.filter()` to keep that element in the set.

So at the end, we're left with only those elements that are duplicates, and we can then do a [`remove()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

---

**Original:**

This will take care of your duplicates for you.

[`$(`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/)[`'div`](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)[`>`](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)[`div'`](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)[`)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/)[`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

---

Comment: +1 for a seriously hot piece of markdown. (And for a good answer to the question.)

Comment: @Gordon: I updated my answer based on the specific requirements you provided. Here's the live example I posted: http://jsfiddle.net/JfPQ7/

Answer (score 3):

On a site I was working on the "seen" jQuery solution wasn't working. What I used was this:

#### HTML

```
<div id="t" class="resevt">2</div>
<div id="t" class="resevt">tues</div>
<div id="w" class="resevt">wed</div>
<div id="th" class="resevt">4</div>
<div id="th" class="resevt">thurs</div>
<div id="f" class="resevt">fri</div>
<div id="count"></div>
```

#### jQuery

```
var ids = [];
$('*').each(function() {
    if (this.id && this.id !== '') {
        if (ids[this.id]) {
            $(this).remove();
        } else {
            ids[this.id] = this
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
            // REMOVING SECOND DUPLICATE SECTIONS OF DIVS HERE 
            \$("div[id^='EXTRACTION_']").each(function(){
               var ids = \$('[id='+this.id+']');
               if(ids.length>1 && ids[0]==this)
               {  
                     \$(ids[1]).remove();
               }
            });
```

Comment: That'll work, but it's pretty inefficient. You're doing repeated DOM selection for elements that you already have. You could achieve something *very* similar though if you cache the original selection result in a variable, say `var extracts = $("div[id^='EXTRACTION_']")` then in your `.each()`, do a `.filter()` against that set using your selector. You could also get rid of the `if()` if you used `.slice()`. So inside the `.each()` it would look like `extracts.filter('[id='+this.id+']').slice(1).remove();`. This way you're not touching the DOM after the initial time. Anyway, just a thought.